Noether normalization for Laurent polynomial algebras
Let $k$ be a field and $n\geq 1$.
Let $A=k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n,X_1^{-1},\dotsc,X_n^{-1}]$ be the algebra of Laurent polynomials in the variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ over $k$.
Let $B=A/I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $A$.

Is there necessarily a subring $B_0$ of $B$ such that $B$ is integral over $B_0$, and $B_0$ is isomorphic to $k[Y_1,\dotsc,Y_t,Y_1^{-1},\dotsc,Y_t^{-1}]$ for some $t\geq 0$?

In other words, I am looking for something like the Noether normalization theorem, but for Laurent polynomial algebras rather than polynomial algeras.
Edit (possible strategies):

Since $A/I$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, Noether normalization says that $A/I$ is integral over a subring isomorphic to a polynomial algebra over $k$ in $d$ variables. I can prove that $A$ has Krull dimension $n$, and so $d \leq n$. Not sure if that helps because I don't see how to extend the polynomial algebra to a Laurent polynomia algebra, and I see no reason for this to be possible in general.
Maybe we can consider the subring $A'=k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ of $A$, and the ideal $I\cap A'$ of $A'$. Then $B'=A'/I\cap A'$ is integral over a polynomial subalgebra $B'_0$. We can view $B'$ as a subalgebra of $B$, and now my idea is to localize by inverting $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$, but that doesn't seem to bring us to the desired conclusion.
Maybe we can imitate the proof of Noether normalization? Say assuming that $k$ is infinite because then the proof is simpler and a linear change of variables works to prove Noether normalization. The proof is inductive, adding on generator of the polynomial algebra at a time. But this is unlikely to work, because a "generic" Laurent polynomial is not invertible, while the usual proof of Noether normalization works by showing that a generic element works as the next generator of the polynomia subalgebra.
Maybe a geometric intuition would work? Say $k=\mathbb{C}$ (I know that algebraic geometry is more general, but I don't understand it well yet). Well, in that case, $A$ corresponds to the subset $V$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ of points where no coordinate is $0$. Now, $A/I$ corresponds to a subset of $V$. A subring of $A/I$ isomorphic to an algebra of Laurent polynomials will correspond to a map onto an algebraic set similar to $V$ (but possibly of a lower dimension) with finite fibers (finite fibers is not enough for integrality, but I'm just gaining intuition). So I can start with ordinary noether normalization to obtain an integral map to $\mathbb{A}^d$ for some $d$, and then hopefully tweak things such that no point with a zero coordinate is in the image.


An alternate geometric idea, you have lots of projections onto smaller dimensional tori from smaller Laurent sub rings, does one of these (of the correct dimension) work? A counterexample would have relations for every torus, this is a lot of relations...
